# Scope on number of items in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose we have a `Tag` model with many associated `Post` (or none) via a `has_many` association.

Is there an efficient way to select only the tags that do have a `tag.posts.size > 0` via a scope ?

Something that would behave as follows:

```
scope :do_have_posts, -> { where("self.posts.count > 0") } #pseudo-code
```

Thanks.

Comment: While a query might work now, I think adding posts_count:integer to tags will be more efficient for the future. You can update this field  using the counter_cache option (see API docs), or manually update the tag's posts_count field when you save or delete a post using callbacks.

Comment: I too thought this was the most efficient way to go - until I saw @Vimsha 's answer. I guess, especially with a large recordset (a few 100k) scoping on a join is more efficients, as that AR caches the query for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should only return you the tags with posts since rails does an inner join by default

```
scope :with_posts, -> { joins(:posts).uniq }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I missed the `uniq` part ;)
Thanks @Vimsha